# Accessing complex JSON structure & retrieving keys/values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, https

Here's a link to the JSON structure I get:removed

I want to access all of the "message" values, but I'm having a heck of a time doing this in objective C. I have the following elements that contain the JSON data, but I haven't found a way to extract it with any reliability. Any help us greatly appreciated!

```
NSString *urlString = [myURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

Comment: Why are you converting from `NSData` -> `NSString NSUTF8StringEncoding` -> `NSData` ??  Also you have said you having difficulty with accessing elements reliably ... I see no attempt to access them at all, what is the question?

Comment: I've made multiple attempts, but with no luck. I didn't want to post each and every attempt.

Comment: I'd rather try to find an issue with some attempt rather than do your work for you

Comment: Roger that, let me get it posted!

Comment: Hah! Simon, I started reconstructing one of my attempts to show you how it didn't work and crashed, but it worked! Doh! I'll update post with my answer. Thanks for not being a crutch!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up solving the problem by chance!

```
 NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

 NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

 NSArray *dataArray = [json valueForKey:@"data"];

 NSLog(@"Messages = %@", [dataArray valueForKey:@"message"]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware, but you could also use [dataArray valueForKeyPath:@"data.message"];.